# Phidget RFID reader

Tags: linux, python-3.x, rfid

Im trying to run Python script(example script) and I get this error:

```
OSError: libphidget22.so.0.0.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

However I installed every lib required.

[Here is the link to any example code Im trying to run with this error.](https://www.phidgets.com/?view=code_samples&lang=Python)

[Phidget I have](https://www.phidgets.com/?tier=3&catid=81&pcid=72&prodid=23)

Im working on Linux, anyone could possibly help me?

Comment: Have you checked libphidget22.so.0.0.0 exists in your library folders? Version 0.0.0 seems curious...

Comment: I do not find anything thats called this way in my Ubuntu.

Comment: Then you didn't install libphidget22 correctly. Follow the advice on https://www.phidgets.com/docs/OS_-_Linux#Getting_started_with_Linux.

Comment: libphidget22:i386 is already the newest version (99:1.0.0.20170720-
    1+deb8).
    libphidget22-dev:i386 is already the newest version 
    (99:1.0.0.20170720-1+deb8).
    libphidget22java:i386 is already the newest version 
   (99:1.0.0.20170720-1+deb8).
    phidget22admin:i386 is already the newest version 
   (99:1.0.0.20170720-1+deb8).
   phidget22networkserver:i386 is already the newest version 
   (99:1.0.0.20170720-1+deb8).

However, still nothing.

Comment: I have the exact same issue when trying to run the example for a digital output `python DigitalOutput.py`...

Comment: The C example for the DigitalOutput works fine ... (be careful, the docs to build the C example are outdated)

Comment: C example works fine for me, python libraries make problem but I found out why: apparently my architecture is not supported and it does not look like it will be supported anytime soon. [Here is a topic on their official forum for those interested](https://www.phidgets.com/phorum/viewtopic.php?f=2&p=27478&sid=7fd6116fb096b7ec153bc4ace4e15631#p27478) .